# 2- vs 3-argument open with '-'

Tags: perl, io, stdin

The following opens `STDIN` and then echos user input:

```
open my $in, '-';
print "You said: $_" while(<$in>);
```

However, the following snippet dies because it can't find any file called '-':

```
open my $in, '<', '-'; # dies
print "You said: $_" while(<$in>);
```

Why does the two-argument `open` work for this but the three-argument `open` dies? I was hoping for a simple method of opening either a file or STDIN based on user input, and I don't want to use 2-argument open.

Comment: That's how open() is designed — documentation is explicit on this. 3-arg version allows to open file with any name including '-', 2-arg version is a convenient wrapper around sml dup() at perl level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[perldoc -f open](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#open-FILEHANDLE-EXPR):

> In the two-argument (and one-argument) form, opening `<-` or `-` opens `STDIN` and opening `>-` opens `STDOUT`.

I think this makes it clear that the special treatment of `-` is specific to the one- or two-argument forms.

You could just assign `\*STDIN` to your `$in`, or open a file based on user input.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, you can use `STDIN` instead of opening it explicitly,

```
use autodie;

my $in;
$in = ($file eq "-") ? \*STDIN : open($in, "<", $file) && $in;
```

Answer (score 2):

Three-arg open fails because there's no file named `-`. That's the whole point of three-arg open. Gotta have a way of opening files without the file names being treated as code!

---

This should do the trick:

```
open(STDIN, '<', $qfn)
   if $qfn;
```

---

Technically, there is a way of opening STDIN with three-args `open`.

```
# Creates a new system handle (file descriptor).
open(my $fh, '<&', fileno(STDIN));
open(my $fh, '<&', \*STDIN);
open(my $fh, '<', "/proc/$$/fd/".fileno(STDIN));  # Linux

# Creates a new Perl handle for the existing system handle
open(my $fh, '<&=', fileno(STDIN));
open(my $fh, '<&=', \*STDIN);
```